# solve an Isoperimetric problem in calculus of variation using Maxima open source.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, maxima-software

Kind help to solve the below problem via maxima program

Find the extremal of the functional $\int_0^1((y^{'})^{2} + x^2)dx$ under the constraint $\int_0^1 y^2 dx\,=\,2$ and having $y(0)\,=\,0$ and 
$y(1)\,=\,1.$  Using Maxima programming.

I tried Like the below code kind help not coming

```
kill(all)$
ratprint: false$
depends(f,[x,y])$
depends(g,[x,y])$
depends(y,x)$
declare(P,real)$
assume(P>0)$ (As positive or negative or zero error was giving)
z: diff(y,x);
f:z^2+x^2;
g:y^2;
h:f+P*g;
h1:diff(h,y);
h2:diff(h,z);
h3:h1-diff(h2,x);
h4:ode2(h3,y,x);
h5: bc2(h4,x=0,y=0,x=1,y=1);
hr:  trigrat(h5);
h6:integrate((rhs(hr))^2,x,0,1);
h7:solve(trigrat(h6)=2,P);
trigrat(rhs(h7[1]));
```

Need help

Answer expected from maxima

```
y= %k1*%e^(sqrt(l)*x)+%k2*%e^(-sqrt(l)*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be handled easily without the help of a symbolic processor so calling

$$
f(x,y,y',\lambda) = (y')^2+x^2+\lambda y^2
$$

we have

$$
f_y-\left(f_{y'}\right)'=y''-\lambda y = 0
$$

and after solving the ODE we have

$$
y = c_1 e^{\sqrt \lambda x}+c_2 e^{-\sqrt\lambda x}
$$

with the boundary and integral conditions we need to solve

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
c_1+c_2 & = & 0\\
c_1 e^{\sqrt \lambda}+c_2 e^{-\sqrt\lambda} & = & 1\\
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\lambda }} \left(e^{\sqrt{\lambda }}-1\right) \left(c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda }}+c_2\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda }} & = & 2
\end{array}
$$

thus obtaining the constants $c_1, c_2, \lambda$ Here making the substitution $c_2 =-c_1$ we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
c_1 & = & -c_2\\2 c_1 \cosh \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\right) & = & 1\\
\frac{2 c_1 \left(\cosh \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\right)-1\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda }} & = & 2
\end{array}
$$

This last step should be concluded using an iterative process which is not explicit in the MAXIMA script.

I hope this helps.